# Installing Qt from source, v 4.8.6

Tags: qt

I am attempting to compile Qt from source and I got an error during the instillation:

```
In file included from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/FastAllocBase.h:84,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/HashCountedSet.h:25,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/Collector.h:27,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/JSCell.h:26,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/runtime/JSAPIValueWrapper.h:28,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/API/APICast.h:29,
                 from ../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/API/JSBase.cpp:30:
../3rdparty/javascriptcore/JavaScriptCore/wtf/TypeTraits.h:173:69: error: ‘std::tr1’ has not been declared
     template<typename T> struct HasTrivialConstructor : public std::tr1::has_trivial_constructor<T> { };
```

Is this a compiler problem?

Comment: what is `gcc --version` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-27029?focusedCommentId=206970&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-206970):

> This problem occurs when using a MinGW/gcc that defaults to enabling
>   C++11 features, such as newer nuwen MinGW builds.
>
> Until JavaScriptCore is updated to deal with gcc's standard C++ 11
>   support, it must be built without C++ 11 enabled.
>
> Changing mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf to have the following line:
>
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS -std=gnu++98
>
> Allows JavaScriptCore to build.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but how do I edit qmake.conf without unpacking the tarball?

Comment: @Rob Why would you not want to unpack the tarball? You could package the change as a patch file, i.e. the build process would be something like `untar`, `patch`, `configure`, `make`, `make install`.

Comment: @Kuba Ober TBH I am not even sure I understand half of what you said.. I am assuming the patch file would be some type of script that runs when I run make?

Comment: @Rob Not at all. It'd be the input to gnu `patch` utility. I.e. after untarring, you'd run `patch` to modify the `qmake.conf` (and any other files) before the Qt build begins. For over a decade I never met a Qt source that would be usable out of the box (i.e. without patches to the source code), so personally I always have a patch step after the untar/unzip step. I don't know how you can not understand "half" of what I said if you claim that you're building Qt yourself. The steps you take to build it are what I gave above, sans the `patch` step. You better script it for repeatability :)

Comment: @Kuba Ober I am new to Linux sorry. So after I unpack it I can just open in a terminal in that directory and run a command called patch? That will allow me to edit qmake.conf? Could I just look through the unpacked directory for the qmake.conf file directly without running the patch command?

Comment: maybe you need to install a version of gcc that doesn't make C++11 default. 4.8, perhaps? (edit: turned it up to 8)

Comment: The patch command would only work after you made a patch file that describes the changes. Since you’re not using this, I’d suggest ignoring it and modifying that qmake.conf manually. Of course the qmake.conf you’d be changing is different — you’ll need the one for your platform, not the one for Windows. I don’t understand why you wanted to edit the file before untarring the archive anyway. You have to untar, then edit (I.e. manually patch), then configure, then build. You can always retar to retain the modified source. Or create a patch file to apply on top of pristine sources.

Comment: @Rob just edit the conf and modify it, then configure/make/make install. Creating and managing patches is for experts whose job is made easier when they need reproducible builds.

Comment: On linux you should edit the file in `linux-g++` instead of `win32-g++`